# Get title Attribute of image in variable PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays, function, dom

How can I get the `title` from the image tag?

```
$img = '<img src="./img/icons/locale_en.gif" title="English">';
```

I need to get **English** as the output.

Comment: To parse easily HTML, you can use http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: How did you end up with just this string? Isn't it part of a bigger piece of HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regular expressions:

```
$img = '<img src="./img/icons/locale_en.gif" title="English">';
preg_match('~title[ ]*=[ ]*["\'](.*?)["\']~is',$img,$match);
echo "title is ".$match[1];
```

And this is possible too:

```
$img = '<img src="./img/icons/locale_en.gif" title="English"><img src="./img/icons/locale_nl.gif" title="Dutch">';
preg_match_all('~title[ ]*=[ ]*["\'](.*?)["\']~is',$img,$match);
foreach($match as $key=>$val)
{
  echo 'title is '.$match[1][$key]."<br />\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DOMDocument`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) Class.

```
echo $dom->getElementsByTagName('img')->item(0)->getAttribute('title');
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/127054)

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the string to find `title="` and then the closing `"` and get the sub-string in between. Something like this would work:

```
$title = explode(" title=\"", $img);
$title = $title[1]; // get the part after title="
$title = explode("\"", $title);
$title = $title[0]; // get the part before "
```